# Automating merge and publish from development to production. Continuous integration

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

Let's say we have 2 branches: Development and Production
Also we have 2 servers on Azure in different affinity groups.

Is there a way to automate the process so that on person choosing version X that was 'accepted' in development merges code into production branch and publishes to production server ?

Ideally I would want to have a Changset# and set to production that will merge the production branch (with all the required previous changesets) and get published to server.

The chosen changeset **does not** have to be the latest on development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following 4 steps should do it for you:

1) Create a new build definition for Development branch using `TfvcTemplate.12.xaml` (only available in TFS 2013) as it has post-build script option (see image below).

2) Create a powershell script to merge the changes to branch using `tf merge` command. You will have to pass the changeset # to the script using Post-build script arguments.
See this URL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy

3) When you run the build set the `Get Version`(see image below) and it will take the changes from that version. After the build is successful it will merge the changes to the production branch using the step 2 above.

4) Create another build for the Production branch and use the link specified in the below answer to deploy the code to azure on check-in to the branch.

[Can I automatically update a live site after each commit using TFVC and Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791730/can-i-automatically-update-a-live-site-after-each-commit-using-tfvc-and-azure/20793318#20793318)

[image]

You can also look at InRelease (link below) for Release Management and automation (not supported for Visual Studio Team Services yet)

http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/release-management-vs.aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: Release Management for VS (formerly InRelease) doesn't support Team Foundation Service, otherwise that would be my suggestion as well.