# Can I automatically update a live site after each commit using TFVC and Azure?

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-web-roles, continuous-delivery

For each commit I want to have a live version with the committed code using TFVC and Windows Azure.

If a developer commits something I want to be able to test it on dev.mysite.com. How can I setup this using azure and TFVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below URLs for details on how to do that:

http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/deploy-to-azure-vs -- Easier option
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/continuous-delivery/